# Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations from 27.0.2 to 27.0.2-preview1

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build the simple sample project from https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-walkthrough

I am getting following error while building in VS 2019:

```
Warning NU1605  Detected package downgrade: 

Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations from 27.0.2 to 27.0.2-preview1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 Walkthrough.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 27.0.2-preview1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette 27.0.2-preview1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2-preview1 -> Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime 1.0.3 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations (>= 27.0.2) 
 Walkthrough.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 27.0.2-preview1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette 27.0.2-preview1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2-preview1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations (= 27.0.2-preview1)   Walkthrough.Android C:\Users\XYZ\Source\Repos\xamarin-forms-walkthrough\src\Walkthrough\Walkthrough.Android\Walkthrough.Android.csproj
```

[image]

Comment: This is a warning, you could ignore it, I download from this link, I can run it normally.If you cannot run it, please delete the `obj` and `bin` folder, rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a `Xamarin` project and updated `Xamarin.Forms` on just One of my `main.csproj` then got the `NuGet Warning NU1605`.

I resolved it by simply right-clicking on Solution 'project-name'(4 project) then Manage NuGet and there where several updates I had missed, one of them being `Xamarin.Forms`.
Updated all of them and the warnings went away.